# Finding all complex solutions of $\sin(z) = 1$ - where do I go wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I know that this question has been asked before - I am not interested in other solutions, I am interested in understanding why my solution is wrong.

Using $$\sin(z)= \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} = 1$$

I multiply both sides by $2i$ and get that
$e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = 2i$

and now it will suffice to show that $\Re(RHS)$ = 0. Using the fact that $e^{iz} = e^{i(x + iy)} = e^{ix - y} = e^{-y}(\cos x + i \sin x)$ I get that

$$e^{y}\cos x - e^{-y} \cos x = 0 \implies \cos x(e^y - e^{-y}) = 0.$$

This is true if $y = 0$ or $x = \frac \pi 2 + 2\pi n$ for integer $n$.

But this is wrong, since if $y = 0$ then $\sin(z) = \sin(x) = 1$, which is not true for all $x$, so certainly something has gone wrong here. What is the mistake?

Comment: Why did you consider only the real part of $e^{iz}-e^{-iz}$?  What about the imaginary part?

Comment: "and now it will suffice to show that $\Re(RHS) = 0$"?

Comment: @EricWofsey oh ok I see. Showing the real parts are equal is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: What do you mean by taking the real part of the right-hand side and making it $0$? Which right side are you referring to?